# HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed (jax-rs service)

Tags: android, rest, jersey, tomcat7

Jax-rs service return **HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed**.

**Service:**

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("login")
public User Login(@QueryParam("u") String username, @QueryParam("p") String password) {
   return UserDAO.getInstance().getLogin(username,password)
}
```

**Android:**

```
 public static Boolean Login(User user) {
     String url = "http://myserver.com/AndroidServis/rest/login?u={u}&p={p}";
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
     
     HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String > ();
     params.put("u", user.getUsername().toString());
     params.put("p", user.getPassword().toString());

     HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

     restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
     restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
     HttpEntity < Korisnici > response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity,User.class, params);

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for the server to have a `@Consumes` annotation on the `@GET` method, as this is typically only used for `PUT` or `POST` requests where the client is sending some content to the server.
Can you remove this?

Then also remove this from the client code.

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

and you may need to uncomment the line you have commented out:

```
headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
```

This tells the server what content type is expected in the response so must match what the @Produces of the service.